# NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification fails when app is closed by clicking red cross and reopened

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsworkspace

I am working on a Mac OS app which aims at keeping track of frontmost window applications used by user. The code is like this :

```
@interface MDAppController : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
NSApplication    *currentApp;
}
@property (retain) NSApplication *currentApp;
@end

@implementation MDAppController
@synthesize currentApp;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(activeAppDidChange:)
        name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil];
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(activeAppDidTerminate:)
        name:NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification object:nil];
}
return self;
}
```

The `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` fails to notify when  an application is closed by clicking on cross button at top left and then reopened. 
If i quit the application from dock and reopen it, then `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` works fine.
Any suggestions why it is not working in previous case ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience of developing MacOs apps, but an app doesn't exit on clicking the left-top cross. Only that window closes. You may need to use some other method for that.

Comment: Yes, i get that. When app is closed by cross button, it only deactivates but doesn't exit. In that case `NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification` works. But when i am reopening the app after closing it `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` fails to notify. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about MacOs development. That was only what I have noticed using MacOs.